# How do I run a python file in a different directory from another python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, python-import

During the course of my python program, I have generated the following string

"D:\something_else.py"

Lets say there are other resources in D: that something_else.py requires.

How would I go about running something_else.py from my code, which let's say is being run from C:\Users\Someone\Desktop?

Right now I'm using the following:

```
from subprocess import call 
call(["python",pythloc])
```

This gives me an error as it's able to find only something_else.py and is unable to find the other resources that something_else.py needs which are in the same folder as something_else.py

Comment: does your folder has `__init__.py`

Comment: Set `cwd` in `call`: `call([xxx], cwd="D:\\")`

Comment: Change pythloc for the abs PATH to the python file you Want to call. If you Want to use relativa paths use os. Path(__file__) to build your PATH. That shows the loción of the python file you are running

Comment: What kind of resources by the way, do you have something like D:\images\\*.jpg" ?  Seems like you might do better to make something_else.py a little smarter about where to look for resource(s) but hard to say without know about their nature (are they in the same directory as something_else.py? subdirectories?)

Comment: @VaibhavVishal No, my project is quite large and doing that would cause more problems than it would solve

Comment: @E.Serra pythoc was the absolute file path, but because the cwd of the subprocess spawned by call was where my current program was being run, it was unable to see any of the resources that somethingelse.py would use

Comment: @jgreve Without going into too much detail: other python files, along with a few yaml and CSV files

Comment: @Sraw THANK YOU! I did that and it worked perfectly! I didn't think to look for a cwd parameter for the call([..) function

Answer (score 3):

Besides the fact that you need to be careful with "\" and instead of :

```
   locationDir="D:\something_else.py"
```

prepend your string with r:

```
   locationDir=r"D:\something_else.py"
```

you can simply set  the PYTHONPATH environment variable to point to the directory in which sit the other modules.

See here for additional informations :

https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Comment: Same with mine. Looks like it's some `downvote and run` show going on. I would personally appreciate if downvoter leaves a comment telling what is wrong, which may help the person writing the answer, as well as anyone who reads it later.

Comment: Agreed on "why downvotes", they both look good to me so +1.  I just went through all kinds of headache trying to understand this and seems like you both explain it well and concisely.  (I ended up using PYTHONPATH myself because I have lots of shell scripts calling things so that seemed slightly more clear than tweaking sys.path in python code.  If I had just *.py files I'd probably tweak sys.path )

Comment: ahh, I just saw the OP's part about "other resources" so apparently the "somethingelse" code @glopquestions wants to call assumes those resources are somewhere relative to the whatever whatever somethingelse lives in.  Which makes me think the other program needs to be smarter about finding those resources.

Comment: @NabilGhodbane thanks for the answer! Your method works generally, just not for my particular usecase as somethingelse.py is intended to reside in different drives and different locations. Not sure why you were downvoted, it's a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you can have the mentioned folder as part of the project itself, you can turn that into  python package, simply by adding an empty file in the folder named `__init__.py`

If it is on some other path like "D:\some_directory\", which has `something_else.py` along with other dependencies, do this along with your import statements:

```
sys.path.append(r"D:\some_directory\")
from something_else import some_useful_function, some_useful_class
```

It will add the mentioned directory to your `sys.path`, and then you can import anything from python files kept there, and just call the functions as usual.

If you are using any IDE like PyCharm, it may still show you `unresolved errors` for the 2nd line, as part of import checks. But the code will simply work when you run it.

It's almost never a good idea to call a python script from other(`python something.py`), when you can just import and call functions, with a better control & error checking.

Comment: It would be great if downvoter could also call out the reason for disagreement.

Comment: Again, I'm not sure why your answer was downvoted - it's a way to solve the problem by getting rid of the problem entirely. I can see that particular workaround working, but definitely not for my usecase as importing individual functions and classes from somethingelse.py is definitely not an option for me

Comment: Yeah, never mind that downvote. Whoever downvoted all these answers, was probably not interested in coming back and reading the comments. :D
Btw, If it works for you, you can have a main function inside the something_else.py, which basically does the same thing, that your script does. Just wanted to highlight that, calling a function gives you more control in terms of error checking, etc. But you obviously are the best judge of your use case.